# How do I set up a two-way binding to ancestor properties in a UserControl in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, user-controls

Here is the XAML for my user control:

```
<UserControl x:Name="titledTextBox" x:Class="VitalStats.View.Controls.TitledTextBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"
    >

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="titleTextBlock" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       Margin="12,5,0,-5" 
                       Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=titledTextBox, FallbackValue=Title Here}" 
                       FontSize="20" 
                       Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="inputTextBox" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=titledTextBox, Mode=TwoWay}"/>   
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

and this is what my code-behind looks like,

```
// Usings here

namespace VitalStats.View.Controls
{
    public partial class TitledTextBox : UserControl
    {

        [Description("A TextBox with built in title")]
        public TitledTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)  )
            {
                this.Title = "Title Here";  
            }
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get { return this.GetValue(TitleProperty) as string; }
            set { this.SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(TitledTextBox), null);

        public string Text
        {
            get { return this.GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }
            set { this.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TitledTextBox), null);

    }
}
```

The binding work when reading data into the UI (so the `Title` property works OK) however 
when reading from th UI (i.e. trying to access `Text` from the code) the property is always null implying that the binding is only one-way (despite the `Mode=TwoWay` property).

I am aware (thanks to XamlZealot's answer) of the `FindAncestor` binding, however `AncestorType` does not exist in Windows Phone 7 (or Silverlight) XAML namespace.

How then do I set up a two-way binding to a `UserControl` property from within the `UserControl`?

This is on Windows Phone 7 (7.1 project).

Answer (score 0):

Try a `RelativeSource` Binding in lieu of the `ElementName`:

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Title, FallbackValue=Title Here}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately for WP7 it seems that `AncestorType` is not supported in Windows Phone and Silverlight - is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

So the following is perhaps not what I asked but what I used to solve the problem. Since all I wanted to do was link the text of the title `TextBlock` to `Title` on the `UserControl` and the same for the text in the input, the code behind can look like this,

```
public string Title
{
    get { return this.titleTextBlock.Text; }
    set { this.titleTextBlock.Text = value; }
}

public string Text
{
    get { return this.inputTextBox.Text; }
    set { this.inputTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

No need for `DependencyProperties` etc.